# multiple shared connections with VPN and same subnet

Tags: networking, debian, vpn, connection-sharing

Please bear my ignorance, I'm learning a lot about networking and debian.

I want to use my Debian server (with multiple lan dongles) to share my vpn (nordvpn) connection to multiple clients in my home network. The ideal setup looks like this:

```
Wan router (internet access) dhcp server with ip 192.168.20.1
|
|-Debian eth0 with nordvpn. acting as DHCP server with ip 192.168.0.1
.....|
.....|-Router1 on eth1 of debian acting as bridge 192.168.0.2
...........|-Client1 of Router1 with ip 192.168.0.3
...........|-Client2 of Router1 with ip 192.168.0.5
.....|-Router2 on eth2 of debian acting as bridge ip 192.168.0.6
...........|-Client3 of Router2 with ip 192.168.0.7
...........|-Client4 of Router2 with ip 192.168.0.8
.....|-Router3 on eth3 of debian acting as bridge ip 192.168.0.9
.....|-Router4 on eth4 of debian acting as bridge ip 192.168.0.10
```

You can see the pattern emerging.

I'm currently able to set up the Routers with working internet using shared connection in the debian server but I need to be able for Client1 to see and ping Client3 and other on my network. The problem is that when sharing connection the server assigns different subnets to each interface (eth1=192.168.10.1, eth2=192.168.20.1 etc).

Ive tried bridging the interfaces and sharing connection to the br0 but no success connecting it to internet, Ive also tried bonding the interfaces without success and my last intent was with DnsMasq and routing but I'm a bit lost at the moment.

So, why Im doing this? I want a machine that is able to share the vpn but also run a plex server, adblocker, samba server and Homebridge for my home, I was able to set up all and the only problem Ive run into is the clients don't see each other.

Any advice, tutorials or pointers on how to do this are appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What is a "Router" referring to in this case? (And what does "acting as a bridge" mean, given that it's the practical opposite of acting as a router?) Can you show your actual configuration from `ip addr`, `ip route`?

Comment: It sounds like you should connect switches to the ethNs (with the ethNs enslaved to one same bridge) instead. But don't worry, normally you can use home routers as switches one way or another, so most likely you don't need to replace them.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'm using two apple extreme routers in bridge mode, not in DHCP, so they request the IP for the clients to the debian server. The problem is that each ethN has a different subnet and i'm not able to merge that to only one so the clients can speak to each other.

Comment: I added a comment in other board maybe it could be helpful here. My end goal is to be able to share my nordvpn with all the clients, after that the services can be setup in the subnet without problems. What I'm currently facing is that when sharing the connection on EthN each get a different IP from the debian server (eth1 gets 10.4.0.1, eth2 gets 10.4.1.1 etc) so the clients that are behind the router1  eth1 (apple extreme acting as a network switch) cant talk to clients on router2 eth2 (network switch). To do that the server should assign only one ip to all eth ports and that's my trouble.

Comment: You should bridge all the ethNs and configure an IP *only* on the bridge. Starting from there you then deal with route(s) and most likely, NAT.) (ethNs here probably don't include eth0, since you want the ClientNs to use the VPN.)